# Javascript eslint error for require, export and console field

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, atom-editor

I have made a script for sending push notifications to my Firebase server, but javascript eslint is throwing error for const first.

Then I found on Google that I have to put ecmaVersion = 6 in my .eslintsrc file.
I did that then it is showing error on require, exports and console field.

I am using Atom as my compiler for code. This is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.printUrl = functions.database.ref('images/{uid}').onWrite(event => {
    var request = event.data.val();
    var payload = {
        data:{
            url : request.url,
            location : request.location
        }
    };

    admin.messaging().sendToTopic(request.topic, payload)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log("Successfully sent message : ", response);
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log("Error sending message : ", error);
        })
});
```

Comment: Please show us the error you get.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: same error for exports and console

Answer (score 7):

You need to let eslint know that you're working in a Node environment to get rid of the require and exports errors. So by adding this to your eslintConfig:

```
"env": {
   "node": true
 }
```

In order to allow the console.log, you will have to turn on the rule by adding this to your eslintconfig:

```
"rules": {
  "no-console": 0
 }
```

You can find more information here: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Comment: 18:13  error  Unexpected console statement  no-console
  21:13  error  Unexpected console statement  no-console

Comment: could not find eslintConfig file so made first change in .eslintrc.js and second in .eslintrc.json

Comment: You should only have one config file for your eslint. So either a `.eslinrc.js` or a `.eslintrc.json`. And now the `require` and `export` statements aren't erroring anymore right?

Comment: Aaah and I'm sorry, the no-console rule value should be set to `0` not `2`. Check my edited answer.

Comment: still getting the same error bro. I even created a new file .eslintrc.js in my project folder but it was unyeiding

Comment: Can you post your config?